# Renormalization condition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Can any on explain to me, why renormalization condition $$\Sigma(\gamma_\mu p^\mu=m)=0,$$ for one loop implies $$\Sigma_2(m)=m\delta_2-\delta_m~?$$ In the original $\Sigma_2$ we had $ m_0$ which is the bare mass right? I don't completely understand how shifting to renormalized mass brings in the counter terms in $\Sigma_2(p)$. This is from Peskin eq 10.40 and 10.42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of P-Sh $\Sigma_2(p)$ is not a complete NLO the electron propagator. Instead it is the contribution of the one-loop diagram 7.15. In the naive perturbation theory this really is the only contribution. But in the renormalized perturbation theory in this order there is also the contribution of the counterterm, i.e. the full NLO is
$$i(\gamma^\mu p_\mu\delta_2-\delta_m)-i\Sigma_2(p)$$
And it is vanishing of this construction when $\gamma^\mu p_\mu=m$ that gives you 10.42

So the renormalized perturbation theory works this way: you include all Feynman diagrams, now with physical values of parameters. But also you should include all possible diagrams where you change some of the lines and vertices with counterterm lines and vertices. What you should remember is that every counterterm line or vertex makes the order of perturbation expansion higher.